# Ubuntu 20.4 won't boot. grub rescue? At least recover my files

Tags: boot-repair

I was formatting an external SSD and it wasn't working and the next time I tried to start up my laptop . . . . . grub rescue>
I looked at a few articles about how to use commands to get it to work and that didn't help.   I downloaded an iso - rescatux - put it on a USB stick and tried a number of their automated buttons, but that didn't work.  Then I thought if I used the Ubuntu try/install disk, I could at least copy all of my files onto an external hard drive.
Isn't there some simple way to get it to boot again?
Thank you

In the "files" program, I guess all my old stuff is on the "computer" icon.  I don't know where to look to find my downloads and documents though.   Anyone know how to navigate the file system?
One way or the other, either get it to boot again or copy all my files, I want that computer back to working.
Thanks again.

OK, I did do the sudo blkid, lsblk and gparted and it shows UNallocated space.  (cr*p).   But like I said, I was watching TV on it for hours after messing with that disk.   Is there any way to recover the disk?

Comment: It's hard to know where to begin based on your problem description. Worst case, you formatted your internal drive(s) instead of the external one.   Some good information could be gained by booting the system with a live USB and editing your question to include the output of `sudo blkid` and `lsblk` or a screenshot from `gparted` showing the partitions on the pc - not the usb.

Comment: I also had the thought that maybe I formatted my main drive but then remembered I tried to format that SSD in the afternoon but was still watching TV on that computer all evening.   I don't know what 'booting the system with a live USB' means.    I can simply boot and get to the grub rescue> prompt or I can boot with the try/install DVD, but don't know what the term 'live USB' means.

Comment: Don't you remember the "Try Ubuntu" when you installed it? That is the live session.